# Comments on posts with pending suggested edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This is not really a bug, but I just ran across a case where someone did an edit, then commented *on the post* to explain why.

That makes sense to the editor, because he sees his suggested edit, but it won't make sense to anyone else until the edit gets accepted.

And it's even worse if the edit gets rejected.

Things are further complicated if the comment inspires the original author to edit too [Peer review Approve/Reject after subsequent author edit has occurred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/peer-review-approve-reject-after-subsequent-author-edit-has-occurred)

Answer (score 2):

The review page needs a comment field that allows the user who rejected or accepted the edit to say why.

Comment: This is not quite the same thing, but I totally agree that there needs to be someway to 'educate' new editors: see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75973/how-to-edit-can-we-agree-on-an-editing-policy/76695#76695) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested edits cannot be submitted without an edit comment -- the edit comment is *required* in this case.

Comment: I assume the question is about *additional* comments (normal comments), *after* the edit has been submitted.

Comment: @Arjan, yes, that was what I meant, though the question title could have been less ambiguous.

Comment: What about [comments inducing/justifying the otherwise too radical edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150142/146482)?