# Is it typical/appropriate to attempt to communicate with Suggested Edit reviewers through the suggested edit comment?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Slightly different from [Allow Suggested Edits reviewers to leave comments for other reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174221/201013) since I'm considering the interaction between edit Suggester <-> Reviewer, not Reviewer <-> Reviewer.

Since I've started editing, I notice I'm not always sure about certain changes to make (ie, should *this* tag be added or *that* tag removed?). I always try to be descriptive in my edit comments as well, and this led me to wonder how important my comments were to reviewers.

I'm not familiar with how the suggested edit queue works/looks like or what tools are available to suggested edit reviewers, but are my suggested edit comments significant? If so, would it make sense to suggest to a reviewer that I *think* something needs to be changed (a tag or whatever) but am not entirely sure and would prefer to leave it up to them? **Note: the issue I try to communicate is additional to my (hopefully) substantial edit; I am not talking about explaining the changes I *did* make, but rather one that I *didn't* and would like a reviewer to consider.**

I say "leave it up to them" because I figure most people (who review properly) are more likely to know the best course of action, and also have an Improve button in order to make their own changes to my suggested edit to...edit it.

Comment: Don't know if it's typical, but personally I'd enjoy reading such a comment when reviewing an edit. That said, you can always post your suggestion as an actual comment to the post for the OP and let them decide if it's appropriate or not.

Comment: [Is *this* typical?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Answer (score 6):

The suggested edit review system is not really designed to suggest suggestions for changes. If you're not sure if the change should be made, **don't make the change**. Reviewers are not there to decide whether they "agree or disagree" per say, but to decide whether or not your edit is valid. *You*, the suggester, should be sure of yourself if you're making a tag edit. A suggested edit is certainly not the place to throw something up in the air and say, "Hey! What do you think?" Leave the tags to someone else if you're not sure what they should be.

So, you *should* be describing your entire mindset (or as much of it as possible) in that edit reason to convince the reviewers that your edit *improves* the post.

Also, keep in mind that the comment is not *just* for reviewers. If the edit is accepted, that edit reason is visible to *everyone* in the revision history. It's meant to describe what you changed in that revision and *why*. That way people who come along later know why the change was made, and it may deter edit/rollback wars if another person understands why a post should exist a *certain* way.

**Bottom Line:** The more detail, the better.

I've told people before - when I see an edit I'm not sure about, the edit reason is the first place I look. If it's vague or irrelevant, I head for the Reject button next.

Comment: Right. Currently I don't make changes I'm unsure of, nor will that change. But since reviewers can improve edits I was curious if I could prompt them to look at something specific in the post, which I may not be familiar with (dummy example: should "Thanks" be removed?). I don't want to make a meta post about every possible post I attempt to edit, but I always don't want to be *not* editing at all because I refuse to make half-assed edits. Granted, there are probably other people who may edit the post as well who know better anyways.

Comment: I've edited the question slightly because I think I conveyed myself wrong. Letting you know in case this changes your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what the suggested edit review page has:

[image]

Therefore, yes. The reviewers can see the message and you can put something in there such as "fixed code typo (because the OP confirmed it was a typo in the comments)" or something.

Comment: Thanks for the glimpse. When a post is improved, do I get a notification similar to `Accepted`/`Rejected`? Or does it just fall under `Accepted` in my user page for that edit?

Comment: @Hydronium There is a little checkbox that says "Suggested edit was helpful". If you check it (it's checked by default) then it's registered as an accept. Otherwise it's a reject.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it appropriate?

Most definitely it is. Plenty times when reviewing, I accept an edit due to explanation provided in suggester comments.

And there are times when I reject edits that may well be worthy of accepting if only the suggester had made the rationale clear.

So please do continue writing comments to reviewers.

Comment: While this is true, I'm addressing the part where I'll make a suggested edit and talk to the reviewer about something that I *didn't* explicitly change. Not so much about providing rationale behind my edit (which I already do).