# For Reviewers: Notes and History

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

> Brainwave! Until this is implemented, if it is, consider leaving a comment on a post you are about to vote to close. Prefix it with a bolded **VTC:** to make it easier to identify, like so:
>
> > **VTC:** You spend the entire post describing what your code does without explaining what's wrong.
>
> Using this convention would make it easier for fellow reviewers. You could also use this convention when voting *not* to close:
>
> > **VTC:** The OP edited in the issue. Voting to leave open.

With the recent discussions around the Close Vote Queue (or [striking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike), as the case may be), I've been pondering various solutions that could help the community to review questions more quickly while preserving quality.

I decided to jump back into the queue with that in mind. As I spent several minutes reading a long question which had been voted as "Unclear" (with a long string of comments), it occurred to me that a summary, left by a previous reviewer, would help a lot in understanding why previous reviewers thought that this post was unclear. (The summary would be totally optional - not looking to increase the review time unless the reviewer *wants* to help other reviewers.)

Comments already serve this purpose, but they are less than ideal for two reasons:

1. Comments can be left by nearly everyone. They get cluttered quickly and may not be quickly visible to other reviewers. Scanning comments can, in some cases, take longer than reading the post. (It's also impossible to match comments to people who have actually cast a vote)
2. Comments are visible to all. A reviewer might want to leave a comment to other reviewers, but not one which is visible to all (including, possibly, the OP). A reviewer could opt to leave two comments: one geared more toward the OP, and another geared toward other reviewers. It just gives reviewers more options.

In addition, some of these posts have been edited, but viewing the edits requires leaving the review pane. Also, you can't see when the close votes were cast, making it difficult to tell if the previous votes were cast before the edit of after.

I know that my votes should be based on my opinion of the post as it currently stands, but it would reduce my review time by several minutes if I could see at least a summary of the history, something along these lines:

> `2 days ago`   **Post Created by user134623**
> `2 days ago`   Marshal voted to close as "Unclear What You're Asking"
> `2 days ago`   Dave voted to close as "Unclear What You're Asking"
>                             *The user spends the entire post describing how his code works
>
>                             without ever mentioning what's wrong with it.*
> `1 day ago`     Ross voted to close as "Off-Topic"
> `1 day ago`     **user134623 edited the question ([revision 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/166612/2))**
> `1 day ago`     SnakeEyes7 voted to Leave Open
>                             *User edited in the actual issue with the code*
> `7 hours ago` Bobby voted to Leave Open

If adding a "Close Vote Explanation" is too complicated, or just to get this going more quickly, the summary *could* extract comments from users who have cast a close-vote from the posts' comment history:

> `2 days ago`   **Post Created by user134623**
> `2 days ago`   Marshal voted to close as "Unclear What You're Asking"
> `2 days ago`   Dave commented: *You've explained how your code works, but haven't
>
>                             actually said whats wrong with it.*
> `1 day ago`     Ross voted to close as "Off-Topic"
> `1 day ago`     Dave voted to close as "Unclear What You're Asking"
> `1 day ago`     **user134623 edited the question ([revision 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/166612/2))**
> `1 day ago`     SnakeEyes7 commented: *Voting not to close - OP edited in the
>
>                             issue with the code.*
> `1 day ago`     SnakeEyes7 voted to Leave Open
> `7 hours ago` Bobby voted to Leave Open

Note: Leaving notes for other reviewers was [already suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/allow-suggested-edits-reviewers-to-leave-comments-for-other-reviewers) for the Suggested Edits queue, but I envision something a bit more comprehensive.

Comment: I really like the idea; my only concern would be that it would then take longer for others to review (though shorter for you). This makes sense in the longer term though.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - obviously leaving a comment explaining your close vote would be totally optional, but the revision history could be completely automated. I don't see how this would increase review time for others.

Comment: You can gain some information without the comment but with the comment the reviewer becomes a lot more efficient. It would take longer if a comment was left.

Comment: While I don't have a problem with this feature request, I suspect that it would have little or no impact on the underlying problem.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - I totally agree... but a crutch is better then jumping on one foot any day.