# Why do the number of close votes stay the same if I disagree with a close vote in review?

Tags: discussion, review, voting

I started using the review section of StackOverflow recently, and I noticed that when I disagree with close votes on a question, that the number of close votes on that post stay the same.

So if ten reviewers decide a question should stay open, but four reviewers have decided to close it, then the question gets closed.

Won't this keep questions in the queue longer, and cause the system to tend to close questions that have even a single negative vote on them, despite some reviewers voting to leave it open?

It seems to me that the votes to leave open should be displayed and have some countering effect to close votes, even if it's not a 1:1 ratio.

Is there some mechanism to achieve this that I am unaware of?

Comment: Regarding "It seems to me that the votes to leave open should be displayed" it's already suggested as part of [this bigger request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208572/152859).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [how it works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close/134673#134673):

> - Voting against closing does not override anyone's close vote. However, a sufficient number of "Do Not Close" responses (currently 3) will kick the question out of the review queue and start aging the close votes - regardless of how many views the question has had.
> - If the question is closed, Do Not Close votes do not translate into re-open votes. However, we may use them to prioritize items in the Reopen Queue (when such a thing exists).

If a question you voted to keep open gets closed, you can always vote to re-open it (which would enter it in the re-open queue). I don't have a handy reference, but I imagine the reverse is true when you vote to not re-open questions in the re-open queue.

Comment: @Arjan I see you edit lots of such links. Why?

Comment: Thanks! I tried searching for an answer, but couldn't find one.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, so I can hover and see what it links to, without actually clicking it. And for other Stack Exchange sites (not Meta, unfortunately, though I could change its CSS on my machine): to make my browser show them as visited. (I never visited the link with Yannis' user id embedded in it.)

Comment: Would be nice if that links what be transformed into canonical form automatically.