# More context for reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

I was recently reviewing a suggested edit where the user who asked the question edited an answer to include some stack trace to back up their original question.

This came through as a Suggested Edit, as expected, with the obvious response being a rejected because it was an invalid edit, the stack trace was not relevant the the answer. It was in fact relevant to the original question, though.

What I propose is more context to an edit, rather than just the difference between the post.

A more in depth look at the change, once I had opened the question in another tab, showed me that what the user should have done was edit their own post, as they had been having a conversation inside the comments of the answer with the answer's author.

Something like a simple text field that identifies who is the original author of the question that the answer relates to, and a list of comments underneath that post, as sometimes the answer to why an edit has been made is within the comments and not in the poorly thought out edit comment, could improve the performance of reviewers in such situations.

Comment: Related feature request: [Show comments on suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150142/show-comments-on-suggested-edits?rq=1)