# Show comments while suggesting edits or reviewing first posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, review, suggested-edits

In the first post queue, I see a question where the asker posted important supplemental information in two comments. So I click “edit”, and the comments disappear: all that's left is the standalone editor, with no link to the post, no comments, nothing but the title, body and tag edit boxes.

To get the comment text, I need to open the same URL in a different tab, and copy the comments across tabs. That's not as efficient as it could and should be.

The same issue arises when suggesting an edit from the post itself: the out-of-page editor doesn't show the comments, and doesn't have a link to the page. [Same thing when reviewing suggested edits.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150142/show-the-posts-comments-on-the-suggested-edits-review-interface)

Please always show the comments while editing a post.

Comment: Close enough in my opinion @Thisismuchhealthier, if OP strongly disagree too he can vote to reopen though.

Answer (score 4):

> Please always show the comments while editing a post.

Absolutely. I need this most often in the *Close Review* queue, where the following scenario plays out repeatedly:

1. Someone posts an unclear question.
2. Some users try to get the OP to add information; others vote to close. OP eventually adds a clarifying comment.
3. Reviewing the Close vote, I see that important information is buried in comments, and click Edit to move it into the question.
4. Comments disappear; I curse, cancel edit, open the question in another tab, etc.