# Review queue for questions should show comments on question

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, review, suggested-edits

I recently reviewed a suggested edit on [Java DB constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497779/java-db-constraint) which simply added a tag to a question.  The comment was "added derby tag based on comment", which surely made sense to the editor, but to check whether the edit was appropriate I had to visit the question in a new window to see the comments.  Would it be reasonable to show the comments on questions and answers in the reviews for suggested edits?

A possible problem with this is that the comments justifying the edit may not make sense if the comments on which they were based are later deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show comments while suggesting edits or reviewing first posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193079/218097) or [Showing Whole Threads in Answer-Review Section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148739/218097).