# To remove signature from someone's post, can we suggest an edit or do we have to raise a flag?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, signatures

Signature in a post is not allowed. (FAQ reference: "Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed."). I tried removing signature from two question but my edit suggestions were rejected:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/79666 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/79581

So, should a regular user raise moderator attention flag for removing signature and not make edits in such cases?

Comment: Editing a post to *only* remove a signature is frowned upon here. No problem doing it while making another edit though...

Comment: @fretje: Eh?  I'd support doing that.  Of course, usually there is more that *could* be done to spiff up a post that came with a signature.  They tend to suck in more than one way.

Comment: @Won't: You must have forgotten [The Great Edit Wars](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/) and its aftermath... ;-)

Comment: @fretje: That just says edit wars are bad. Hard to disagree with that. The general rule is that if the original poster rolls back your edit, leave it alone (or flag a moderator to step in and intervene). That doesn't say not to remove signatures.

Comment: I don't understand why the asker should remove his name from the bottom of the question at all...I think writing your name at the bottom of a question or anything else is just showing respect to whom you address.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: Your signature card appears at the bottom of *every* post that you make. It's that giant thing highlighted in gray (or blue or some distinctive color) that contains your gravatar image. Adding your own signature at the bottom of the post is redundant, and strongly discouraged around here. It *will* be removed by someone with edit privileges if you insist on including it.

Comment: @Cody removing that one is ok, but why remove just a name like the ones in Aziz's questions.it is just `Matt`.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: Uhh, same reason? The only thing wrong with that first edit is that he didn't *also* remove *"Thanks in advance"*.

Comment: @Cody: that's why I also mentioned "and its aftermath"... read the comments of that blog post... there has been heavy discussion about whether or not editing a post to *only* remove signatures is ok.

Comment: @fretje: Oh sorry, I don't read comments.

Comment: @Cody Well, anyway then.I don't agree with removing `thanks`es neither.Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for some insightful comments. To summarize, flagging is not required in this case. Editing is recommended but dont just remove the signature, keeping in mind that "no post is so perfect that it cannot be improved somehow". Overall in general [ChirsF](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) gave the right points to consider while making edit suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I was one of the two who voted to reject the first edit.

The reason is simply that you removed just a single word, while also editing the greeting "Thanks in advance" into the question text.

If you had removed both it would probably have been accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't have 2,000 reputation just suggest an edit.

However, you are more likely to get your edit approved if you make other improvements to the post as well, including but not limited to:

- correcting spelling mistakes
- formatting code
- sorting out grammar
- replacing shortened URLs with their full length equivalent
- including links to reference material

Comment: Yes, [no post is so perfect that it cannot be improved somehow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91753/low-rep-users-should-be-able-to-fix-broken-links/91763#91763).

Comment: If a "thanks" or "please" is left in the post after the edit, I will reject the edit.

Comment: I've seen a few of these rejected in the last couple of days.  Removing the signature is valid, so I'm confident that the reason for the rejection is that some other edits should have been done at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not something for which you need a mod's attention.  Suggesting an edit should be sufficient.

While you are suggesting an edit, you should also see if there is anything else in the post that could be improved.