# What should I write to Edit Summary for "Thanks" deletions

Tags: discussion

While editing posts I mostly delete ***Thanks!*** and ***Sorry for my inglese*** and those edits are accepted. I don't have a problem writing Edit Summary as I edited grammar and spelling also. What if I only deleted this lines, what should I write to Edit Summary?

Comment: I generally go for something like "Removing redundant/off-topic comments."

Comment: I'd usually go for "Removed noise"

Comment: "Focus on question"; after removing the apology for being a newb and the thanks.

Comment: You could just write "Brevity" as that's really the root of it, but _try not to_ suggest edits just to remove greetings and salutations. Surely there's something else that you could fix, thus obviating the need for such a description?

Comment: I usually write "Cleaned up post" and leave it to their imagination as to what I did (or they can check the revision history)

Comment: Removal of salutations, etc. is discussed at length and voted on in *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of thing, I usually write **removed unnecessary text**. It's clear enough that new users can understand why it was removed, and works for "*Hello*", "*Thanks*", and "*Sorry*" type messages.

And as others have pointed out, I really try to find something more to fix than just that -- grammar, typos, formatting, etc.

Comment: I use *"Removed unrelated content"*.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest not performing those edits at all, until you have enough reputation to edit without the suggested edit queue. If the only change you make is removing those statements, you are risking having your edits rejected as Too Minor. Some people will accept them, but many (including myself) won't. The reason is that suggested edits require the work of four people (one editor + 3 reviewers; 2 reviewers on most sites), so if they don't make a significant improvement, it is a waste of time and energy. Once you don't need the queue anymore, you can make these edits freely, since it only takes you.

To actually answer the question, I would suggest something like "removed thanks" or "removed noise". Once you have enough reputation to edit without the queue, you can also not leave a message at all, and the system will fill in the default "deleted XXXX characters in body".

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110153/approve-suggested-edits-when-only-the-signature-is-removed) for a discussion of whether these edits should be accepted or not.

Comment: I still like to make a relevant comment - it helps avoid newbies just reverting an edit, as it gives them a reason. Without that, they just see their answer becoming less pleasant (from their POV).

Answer (score 0):

**I would post it as "Removed greeting."** When I started up, I always did a greeting, and they always go removed with the subject "Removed greeting."

Like `ughoavgfhw` said, if you don't have the reputation to edit without peer review, **don't do it.** You add stress to the reviewers, and it wastes everybody's time because someone was trying to be nice when people are really trying to clean up the site.

I don't really mind the greeting either way; it is just there or not, it doesn't affect the content and I usually skim the question and skip it.

And because I couldn't resist the irony:
Thanks for viewing!

Answer (score 0):

I just say "de-thanked", and so far nobody has asked for a link to the meta/FAQ as to why. It's probably too terse, but so far it has been sufficient.

I have yet to have one reverted, but that could just be luck.

I agree with the sentiment that if it's the *only* thing you're editing, don't do it unless you no longer fall into the review queue, otherwise it will almost skyways be rejected as "too trivial", and rightfully so.