# Editing questions, not allowed to fix single char mistakes that kills the formatting and makes the question near unreadable, what gives?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We're discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites)

I just tried to edit a question to fix a single char mistake that killed the formatting of the question and thus made it near unreadable, but i was not allowed, because "surely i could fix more than one char".

To me that seems pretty detrimental to the process. How can the system possibly have a clue what is needed to be fixed? Why would it force me to make more changes to allow me to correct the one big error that was needed?

To me the system seems broken.

Comment: Is it the software that is enforcing this rule, or other users?  Also, please provide a link to the question at hand.

Comment: I did a one-character edit to this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/what-are-the-qualities-of-good-developer.  If it's a software glitch, it's not happening on Programmers.SE.  Does it only happen with suggested edits?

Comment: @Robert You have edit rights there; 2k users can edit however they want. Suggested edits need to be 6+ characters

Comment: It is the software - the site wouldn't allow me to suggest a one-char edit. What question it was regarding isn't relevant at all, since that isn't the point. What i tried to fix was a code block made with backticks where the 2nd backtick was after several line-breaks, and thus the formating didn't work.

Comment: I think the intent is to leave the little fixes to people with edit privileges.  Casting a suggested edit and getting two people to approve it sounds like a lot of ceremony just to change an apostrophe.

Comment: @Robert That is [indeed the intent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites/77257#77257).