# Is there a voting member status that one can work towards

Tags: discussion, privileges, trusted-user

I find myself often agreeing in principle with SO rules but wondering about the  arbitrariness of some of them.  For example, there is an implicit assumption that there is a good chance that someone with less than 2000 rep will be a vandal:

[What's up with the minimum length for edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78159/whats-up-with-the-minimum-length-for-edits)

How was that number determined? How do these limits get decided in general?  Is it an executive decision? Or once you have achieved a certain reputation, does SO extend you an invitation to participate in discussions or polls about such decisions? Is there a "voting member" status that one can work towards?

Comment: "Crack 20,000 reputation on a site and pop your beverage of choice, you're now a trusted user. Put up your feet and watch the truck back up and shower you with some more actions to enact on the good site itself. Untold riches in site functions now avail themselves unto you, such as..." (['trusted-user' tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/trusted-user/info))

Comment: @gnat I wonder if that tag wiki was written by someone with 20k rep... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber nah this was written by [just some random guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/141603/revisions) :)

Comment: I don't see anything in the list of Trusted User privileges that relates to discussing or voting on site regulations such as the 2000 rep required to make minor spelling or grammatical corrections. Do I understand correctly, then, that such regulations are executive decisions and not the product of deliberations by Trusted Users?

Comment: gnat was just posting that as a related item, not an answer (which is why he did not post it as an answer). My 'related question' does answer your primary question here, though.

Comment: Also, please be sure to use @username to reply to people, so they are notified. You only are notified of these comments because it is your post we are commenting to. See how gnat and I did that on the 2nd and 3rd comments.