# How are white spaces counted in edit length restriction?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have encountered 6 chars minumum length edit limitation many times. I read this question and linked blog:
[What's up with the minimum length for edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78159/whats-up-with-the-minimum-length-for-edits)

But I have different findings. I edited longer code [in question/answear] and fixed intendation to display it correctly. I was sure that I removed more than 6 spaces but it still refused to save such edit. Can you please describe the rules and how they deal with white spaces?