# What is the rationale behind 6 character edits?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [We're discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites)

In the [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) explanation it say:

> When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

Sometimes, I see a one character typo that hurts the readability of an answer. I completely understand the need for moderation, but I've abandoned a couple of changes simply because there wasn't 6 things wrong with it.

**What is the reason behind this rule?**

NB. Apologies if this is spelt out somewhere else - I couldn't find it for looking.

Comment: The rationale is that we've yet to see a post that can't be improved in enough ways to get you over that 6 character limit. Sure, there might be a typo you need to fix or some formatting changes you need to make, but look around and see if there's not something *else* you can change to improve the post. Another little change. Combined, that's easily more than the 6 character limit.