# How does one edit bad/old links in posts where the change is less than six characters?

Tags: support

I tried to update the following post:

[a button to change 'javascript:history.go() ' history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458983/a-button-to-change-javascripthistory-go-history/)

to replace the old link:
http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html
with a working one:  http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

But since this was only a change of 4 characters, the edit was not saved, since it needed to be at least 6 characters...   I put it as a comment for now.   Is this the desired practice?   Is there a workaround for this?   I don't want to add random text to a post, and I feel it is useful to keep these links updated...

Comment: Note: Full privileged users with 2,000 reputation don't have this restriction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I think this is quite an edge case; normally the changing of a bad link to a good link would, *in most cases*, consume more than 6 characters.

However...

I think [the official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/811) is that there is *always* some other changes that could be made to the post to bring your edit up to the required 6 character count.

If you're still ***really*** struggling, consider:

> Is this edit *so* important that I *have* to make it.

If you're sure, you could either add a comment as you have done, or in your edit add some filler to make it up to the 6 characters and specify you have done in your edit summary. I for one would get the hint and hit "improve" and remove the filler before accepting your edit.

<sup>If you want to be crafty, you could waste some characters by reorganising sentences or by changing variable names in the code.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that helps clarify the SE position on these type of edits.

Comment: There's always the `<!-- padding -->` option.