# why the 6 letter min. for editing spelling/grammar in questions?

Tags: support, edits, spelling, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We're discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites)

How should one correct spelling or grammar that is under 6 letter change if less than that is not acceptable?

Comment: Basically, you don't. Find something else to fix while you're at it.

Comment: @iight - The people approving your edits have a limited number of approvals per day. We don't want to waste those on single character typos.