# How should I perform substantial edits that cannot meet the 6 non-space character limit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Occasionally I come accross a post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4689230/1), where

1. the lack of code formatting is a significant problem
2. the post is so deliberately simple that further changes disrespect the original author's intent.

How should I attempt to improve such posts, given the 6 non-space character limitation?  Submit an overzealous edit and assume it will be pared down if necessary?  Give up and come back when I hit 2k?

Comment: Reviewing an edit takes two people with edit privileges, fixing a typo or minor formatting only takes one of them. Think economy! Besides, when you reach 2k you might no longer consider such edits important. Really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give up and come back when you hit 2K.

Once you hit that reputation level it is assumed that you know what you are doing.

There are other questions which address the issue of whether simply getting 2K reputation is a good enough guide, but they don't concern us here.

Answer (score 5):

In this case something like

> It's as simple as
>
> ```
> Number((555.55).toPrecision(2))
> ```
>
> as can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5GRb/)

would do the job while retaining the simplicity. Sure, the point of the answer is the code, but making it more readable *as English* by adding a few words is still an improvement.