# What's the logic behind the six character edit requirement?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, character-limit

The six character requirement for edits makes little sense.

I've come across an answer with a typo of one character but without correction, the code is nonetheless redundant.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708024/2971649

(see "Weedkly" that should read "Weekly").

Where is the logic in assuming that a one character mistake is less incorrect or edit-worthy than a six character mistake?

Posting a comment to the said question and tossing a coin as to whether the user will correct their post seems less efficient than allowing unrestricted user-wide editing.

I appreciate that you're perhaps trying to mitigate the moderating queues for edits. Implementing a lower tier of moderators exclusively for spelling/grammatical errors (i.e., for non-expert coders) would allow you to assemble a body of volunteer moderators and thereby allow 1 character editing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23708024/revisions. There are always six characters worth of edits to be done.

Comment: Touché and thank you for the example :-) In this particular case, there indeed was. Allow me to reattempt articulating my inquiry. _Presupposing_ that instances occur in which only 1 character requires amendment, what is the recommended protocol? Should one a) ignore and therefore perpetuate the error or b) superfluously apply extraneous and unnecessary edits to meet the 6 character quota and irrespectively, what is the logic behind the 6 character restriction in support of the illogical processes it presents?

Comment: Apologies for posting a duplicate question. I relied on the auto-suggest feature (in the post editor) instead of more rigorously using the search box prior to starting the question.

Comment: Dupes are no big deal here, Clarus, unless the dupe is pretty easy to find. I generally agree with the top answer on the linked dupe, which is too long to quote here. As for why that's the policy here, the site co-founder said [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/130268), a few years ago: *As a < 2k rep user, you should make reasonably substantive edits. The approval cost for your edit is not free, as it costs the attention of one or more users who have to look at your edit and think about it... if you want to make single-character trivial edits, earn 2k rep.*

Comment: Thanks for the context, Michael. Much of what I'm attempting to express is being debated at the link you've provided.