# How to correct spelling or grammar with 5 or fewer characters?

Tags: support, edits

"Edits must be at least 6 characters".

How can I correct spelling with five or fewer characters please?

Is the edit request still sent in that case when I click "cancel" in the edit view?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77235/344673

Comment: Leave a comment, encouraging the author to edit. Also encourage the author to flag your comment as obsolete once the edit is done.

Comment: Two-stage edit?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I correct spelling with 5 or less characters please?

You don't. If all that can be improved in a post is a single typo, just leave it alone.

It is likely that there are more things that can be improved - most changes will take you over 6 characters.

> Is the edit request still sent in that case when I click "cancel" in the edit view?

No, it isn't. It gets cancelled.

Comment: Guess this is the right answer, though I definitely don't like this rule. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites#comment188371_77233

Comment: @lowtechsun and many people don't like Stack Overflow for its strict approach, downvotes, etc. But those are the things that make it into what it is and intended to keep it this way. For example, if we'll allow suggesting edits changing one character, there will be flood of thousands of trivial edits that will deter the core users from reviewing.

Comment: One way or the other it would be good to have a way to correct less than 6 character errors in spelling, grammar and most of all **code** apart from the two-stage-edit suggested above. I learned to ask better researched and concise questions as well as deal with the downvotes etc. and **love** to improve questions I come across for better readability as well as content.