# Questions on the feature decisions of an SE site

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask a question in this meta site, or related meta site of the SE site about why a SE site has a feature in some way but not in another way(s)?

For example, "why SO is not a SPA (Single Page Application)?" (I wonder if it was related to the other things like SEO, and whether it was a choice over SPA for such reasons even though the SPA way was possible).

Note: I'm asking if it is ok to ask that question, not where to ask.

Comment: In theory such question can be asked on MSE but in the example presented it would be highly subjective unless one of the early devs and/or Jeff hiself answers. And if they do I still expect the answer to be: because in 2008 SPA was not yet a thing or not enough support back then in browsers to make that work. Except for some anecdotal reference why do you think such questions and its answers are valuable? Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369 and the blog with podcasts of the early days: https://stackoverflow.blog

Comment: I have wondered if it was related to the other things like SEO, and whether it was a choice over SPA for such reasons even though the SPA way was possible. However, since you have pointed situation of SPA back in days, it seems this was not the case.

Comment: @Cai What I have asked is about if it is ok to ask that question, not where to ask.

Comment: Oh... fair enough, vote retracted.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the times, yes. Can't say 100% for sure about anything, but I believe your example is on topic both here (since all sites are built in the same way/code) and on MSO.

For such questions the proper tag is [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), as you want to discuss the feature, not ask how to use it ([support](/questions/tagged/support) tag) or to change it ([feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag).

One example is [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites) which discuss the fact suggested edits must change at least six characters in the post.