# Options for rejecting an edit are insufficient

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

In the suggested edits queue, I found [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/113907). It added a [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime) tag, which I think is not correct, because the question wasn't about the `DateTime` type (I have no idea whether ActionScript even has one).

When I tried to reject it, this dialog showed up:

> **Why are you rejecting this edit?**
>
> - copied content
>
>   This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution.
> - invalid edit
>
>   This edit is not an edit, but an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
> - radical change
>
>   This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.
> - style opinions
>
>   This edit is about conflicting opinions on style issues, not the actual substance of the post.
> - too minor
>
>   This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.
> - vandalism
>
>   This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.

But I want to reject the edit simply because I think it is incorrect, which doesn't fit any of the given options.

So, my request is that either:

1. another option is added that says something like “incorrect”, or
2. another option is added that can encompass all other reasons for rejecting an edit, something like “other”.

Comment: Maybe `invalid edit` should start "This edit is incorrect, or an attempt..."

Comment: In this specific case, the rejecting reason could have been "minor edit" as it does not resolve over issues present in the question, such as a sentence not containing a subject.

Comment: Good thing is: waffles [already stated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections/107930#107930): *Based on: [What are the rejection reasons for suggested edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106867/what-are-the-rejection-reasons-for-suggested-edits) I have deployed an initial implementation. [..] We will look at improving the list as we go, we may also allow for free-text if we find the list too limiting (we will review the data).*

Comment: We don't decide who's wrong and who's right by editing. We decide by voting. If the original context of the question has changed so much that it is now "wrong" (whereas it wasn't before, when you could have just downvoted it) then the edit is already a `radical change`. I think more appropriate here is the notion of a `bad tag edit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just revved it, will be deployed soon.

In particular I simplified the decision process.

As a rejector you now need to decide.

1. Is this wrong => `Invalid edit`
2. Is this too timid => `Too minor`
3. Is this too major => `radical change`
4. Is this spam or vandalism => `vandalism`
5. Is this plagiarism => `copied content`

The stats from the weekend are:

```
 
too minor   244
invalid edit    177
radical change  99
style opinions  67
vandalism   37
copied content  16
```

Looking through `style opinions` it seemed that most cases `too minor` would have worked, in some cases it was an `invalid edit` others a mistake.

I do not think we are gaining anything by having `style opinions` hence it is gone.

---

Invalid Edit's new copy is:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Comment: +1 for the same wording as in my comment!

Answer (score 10):

Hmm... With all those reasons (I think there are too many already) it seems like there should be a simple "declined" reason. Maybe one of the existing choices can be reworded to include this use case, but here it is in an *additional* selection:

> - **declined**
>     This edit may contain incorrect, confusing, or misleading information.

Comment: Certainly "style opinions" and "too minor" could be combined, since they both address something not being a substantial improvement. Maybe "invalid edit" and "vandalism" since they both introduce content that doesn't belong there.

Comment: I preferred expanding `invalid edit` I did not want to add any more reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed ([I missed it myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections/107930#comment-278158)).

Responding to the objection that there are already too many options in that dialog, there's one that doesn't belong here: “copied content” is a major rejection reason for tag wikis, but irrelevant for posts. There should be a separate list for tag wikis, containing “copied content” but not “too minor” nor “style opinions”, and “radical change” should have a different description (something like “unbalanced” — I [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106867/what-are-the-rejection-reasons-for-suggested-edits/106875#106875) “Your proposed content does not adequately describe the main use(s) of the tag”.).

Furthermore, until rejection reasons are ironed out, please please **include an “other” option**. It's better to provide vague feedback like “other” than to have to select a misleading reject reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like it like this:

> **Why are you rejecting this edit?**
>
> - invalid edit
>
>   This edit is incorrect, or is about conflicting opinions on style issues not the actual substance of the post, or not an edit but an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
> - too minor
>
>   This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.
> - copied content
>
>   This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution.
> - radical change
>
>   This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.
> - vandalism
>
>   This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.

The "invalid edit" description is too long, but covers the plain incorrect edit/retag case.

I don't see a need for a separate "style" option (too many of them already).

Invalid and too minor need to be at the top, they're the most frequent reasons in my experience.

Comment: Thanks, I made a change to a post to simplify the example code but got invalid edit which I didn't understand, but that falls under style issues which makes more sense.