# Should the writing style be corrected by editors?

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

Some people put a bunch of sentences in one paragraph. Others like to separate their writing a bit more and would write the same thing in 2 or 3 paragraphs. Some people use a lot of abbreviations, while others like to spell out everything they say. Some people don't capitalize their sentences, others like to use a lot of italics to highlight the stress of a sentence. Some use contractions like "I'm", some do not.

These kind of things make the writing style more individual and personal and give each user a sort of own "voice". They are not grammatical or spelling errors that make questions harder to read. Why, then, do people feel the need to edit posts to meet the editor's own criteria for what's standard and "professional"? I understand that Stack Exchange is supposed to be a source of objective knowledge and a resource to use for many years. But must we kill all individuality in the process?

Comment: Grammar and spelling are important. They make things easier to read. I find the lack of capitals and the dense paragraphs in this post difficult to read, for instance.

Comment: Poor spelling and grammar cast doubt upon the veracity of a document.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1807/editing-other-users-posts-for-completely-trivial-reasons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit? Can we agree on an editing 'policy'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75973/how-to-edit-can-we-agree-on-an-editing-policy)

Comment: *"Some people don't capitalize their sentences"* - *"They are not grammatical or spelling errors"* - Um, what?

Answer (score 20):

> they are not grammatical or spelling errors that make questions harder to read

I disagree with that. Using capitals and paragraphs the right way actually makes the post easier to read. And that is exactly what we want! We want a useful, clear Q/A knowledge base.

Of course, we value every single user contributing, and we shouldn't remove all personal style from a post, but making it easier to read is a good thing. Some users here have helped me to to improve the readability of my posts, and I appreciate that a lot.

Personally I have trouble sometimes reading posts on Seasoned Advice. I love cooking, but I am not very familiar with all abbreviations. If I can write those out to make it easier for me to read, and for future users, we have made the site better, for everyone.

Comment: `the right way` what is the right way for one person, will not be right for another. language is a very dynamic and personal thing.

Comment: That is personal sometimes indeed. But you would agree a wall of text is never useful.

Comment: @foerno: Stack Exchange sites are not blogs or social things. Think encyclopedia instead. Also think about people with visual disabilities. The lack of capitals in your post makes it header to read simply because there's much less visual distinction between sentences. Same thing for paragraphs.

Answer (score 10):

Your choice not to use capitalisation and other generally accepted good grammatical style is really no different to someone who doesn't know any better.

The official language of this site is English. If I read [quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com) correctly then less than 50% of the people who visit this site have English as a first language. Many questions and answers are poorly written because of a poor understanding of English language, its usage and the vagaries of its grammar. These usually get 'fixed up'.

Someone editing your posts to conform with more normal English usage should be expected (it's encouraged, we have badges for editing). There are even [tools to help](https://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit) do this.

Answer (score 6):

> These kind of things make the writing style more individual and personal and give each user a sort of own "voice".

Keep in mind that this is a Q&A site dedicated to collecting useful info for everyone.  This isn't a political or literature forum, where no one is concerned about this (and would not be able to edit your posts anyway).  When posts on here are written very cleanly and require little to no additional time to parse the general meaning, it helps make this info more useful to others.  It also shows that this is a more "formal" site and not just another help forum.  We like it to stay this way, which is why users are allowed to edit other posts (with or without peer review).

You shouldn't feel offended if anyone edits your posts in such a way.  If one user somehow makes it worse, then another can come and fix it.  On the other hand, if someone just leaves a rude comment about the post's clarity, then that comment should be flagged for removal.